# Dell Laptop Acting Up

Tags: dell-inspiron

So I have an older Dell Inspiron 1501 laptop.  The battery has used up all of its cycles pretty much. But that, I dont think is the issue.  When I go to start the laptop I have to keep moving the monitor until the computer turns on.  I'm assuming its a loose connection somewhere but I dont understand how the moving the monitor from almost closed to completely ajar would cause the machine to work/not work.  Any ideas as to why this could be happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the lid sensor, as [Nifle suggests](https://superuser.com/questions/200238/dell-laptop-acting-up/200242#200242), you can use the Dell-provided [service manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins1501/en/sm_en/index.htm) for your model of laptop to find it. It might be called the standby switch, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I have a good feeling this is the problem.  Ive tried to turn the computer on with the screen detached but still connected and tried with the sensor pushed in/out but still no luck.  I replaced the CMOS battery and no luck so I think im going to buy a sensor and see if that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Most laptops have sensors that enable the OS to shutdown/sleep/hibernate the computer when you fold down the monitor.

I expect something is wrong with that sensor.

Comment: hm this sounds like it could be the problem.  Do you know what the sensor would be called so I can check for it?

Comment: @meepz - Sorry, no clue whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely two possibilities:

- `Video cable` is loose
- `lid close` switch/sensor is dirty / stuck

If there was a problem with the lid close switch, I would have expected that your computer will often suddenly go to standby if the lid is moved.  Subsequently, you can tell Windows to ignore that switch via Control Panel->Power Options (see pic below).

You can check [Here](http://www.laptoprepair101.com/laptop/2006/07/08/notebook-display-diagram/) for more info.

[image]

Comment: The problem now is that I can't even get the computer to turn on. Ive been trying to get it to turn on for a few hours now and no luck.  Maybe the laptop has finally crapped the bed.  Another thing is that the battery is completely gone so I dont know if this would affect startup despite having the laptop connected to the charger.  Usually it doesnt but maybe since it is an older model it might